# "WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS" doesn't work on Android 11

Tags: android, statusbar, android-windowmanager, window-managers, android-11

I hope you can help me. I have a problem with "WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS", on Android 11 it doesn't work while on previous versions it does. I state that I have an OnePlus with the beta of Android 11 but also on the emulator (Android 11) I have the same problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No solutions for that problem? 
I mean its strange that its not working on Android11 but on 10 isn't it?!